# Mouse click on BarChart elements

Tags: manipulate, plotting

What I would like to do is explore a data set by clicking on elements in a BarChart. I have some existing code which uses a manipulate which I was hoping to modify.

```
classification = {"class1", "class2", "class3"};
cause = {"cause1", "cause2", "cause3", "cause4", "cause5"};
dataSet = Table[{classification[[RandomInteger[{1, 3}]]],
cause[[RandomInteger[{1, 5}]]], RandomReal[{0, 10}]}, {i, 1, 50}];

(*generate the classification BarChart*)
byClass = GatherBy[dataSet, #[[1]] &];
durationByClass = {First[#][[1]], Total[#[[All, 3]]]} & /@ byClass;
classChart = BarChart[durationByClass[[All, 2]], 
ChartLabels -> durationByClass[[All, 1]], 
ChartStyle -> {LightGray, LightGray, LightGray}, 
PlotLabel -> "Data by Classification", ImageSize -> 400];

(*a function to get the cause chart*)
getCauseChartExample[classificationIndex_] := Module[{},
durationByCause = GatherBy[
Select[dataSet, #[[1]] == 
   classification[[classificationIndex]] &], #[[2]] &];
plotData = {First[#][[2]], Total[#[[All, 3]]]} & /@ durationByCause;
BarChart[plotData[[All, 2]], ChartLabels -> plotData[[All, 1]], 
ChartStyle -> LightGray,
PlotLabel -> classification[[classificationIndex]] <> " by Cause", 
ImageSize -> 400]
]

Manipulate[Row[{classChart, getCauseChartExample[classIndex]}], {classIndex, {1,2, 3}}]
```

The output looks like this;

[image]

I would like to replace the Manipulate with the ability to mouse click the bars on the chart on the left and have the corresponding chart display on the right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll work with a minimal example instead of your code.

Start by setting a variable `status`:

```
status=1;
```

Now, create the clickable `BarChart` that'll change the value of `status` depending on what bar is getting clicked:

```
BarChart[{Button[1, status = 1], Button[2, status = 2], 
  Button[3, status = 3]}]
```

Define a data set:

```
data = Partition[RandomInteger[10, 9], 3];
```

Now, build a `BarChart` that will choose a data set depending on the value of `status`:

```
Dynamic@BarChart[data[[status]]]
```

All code in one, easier to copy:

```
status=1;
BarChart[{Button[1, status = 1], Button[2, status = 2], 
  Button[3, status = 3]}]
data = Partition[RandomInteger[10, 9], 3];
Dynamic@BarChart[data[[status]]]
```

Specifically in your case you need to change the first argument in your cause bar chart to this:

```
MapIndexed[Button[#, classindex = #2] &, durationByClass[[All, 2]]]
```

And you need to change the last row to:

```
Row[{classChart, Dynamic@getCauseChartExample[First@classindex]}]
```